# IDLE crash when using multiprocessing on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, crash, multiprocessing, python-idle

If I run this simple code in IDLE in Python 2.7.8, it will pop a window saying "The program is still running! Do you want to kill it?".

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def foo(x):
    return x**2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(2)
    pows = pool.map(foo, range(10))
    print pows
```

Even if I do kill or not (it will ask twice) nothing will happen. I used to use Windows and I've just recently started using Mac OSX (10.9.4), and I don't know if I'm missing something here.

If I run the same code directly in the Python Shell in terminal, it will run fine. Same in iPython notebook. It just won't on IDLE, popping up that message box.

Any ideas? I'd like to keep using IDLE...

here's the log:

```
INFO:root:10221: Started process
INFO:root:10221: Defined foo
INFO:root:10221: __name__ == '__main__'
INFO:root:10221: pool created
```

Comment: Does it produce any output? (e.g. does the print statement run?)

Comment: no output at all... regardless if I chose to kill or not. the cursor keep blinking in the console and nothing happen. seems the same problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760876/python-multiprocess-fails-to-start?rq=1

Comment: When I run this from an IDLE editor with 2.7.13 on Win10, it immediately prints `[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]`.  I don't know whether the OS or version difference is responsible for the different outcome, but I recommend using IDLE with the later 2.x or 3.x release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known issue with the previous version of Pycharm. If you upgrade with the latest version now you can safely use multiprocessing within the console of the IDE without running in this issue any longer.

See here for further informations: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14969

Answer (score 1):

Ref this:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction

Specifically, in the note:

> Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be
>   importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines
>   however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples,
>   such as the `multiprocessing.Pool` examples will not work in the
>   interactive interpreter."

Here's a similar question [Child processes created with python multiprocessing module won't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774585/child-processes-created-with-python-multiprocessing-module-wont-print)

Example of logging activity to a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

def log_msg(msg):
    logging.info("{}: {}".format(os.getpid(), msg))

log_msg("Started process")

def foo(x):
    log_msg("running foo")
    return x**2

log_msg("Defined foo")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_msg("__name__ == '__main__'")

    pool = Pool(2)
    log_msg("pool created")
    pows = pool.map(foo, range(10))
    log_msg("map completed")
    print pows
    log_msg("output printed")

log_msg("Finished running")
```

Example output for me:

```
tom@fannybawz:~$ ./multiproc.py
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
tom@fannybawz:~$ cat example.log 
INFO:root:22238: Started process
INFO:root:22238: Defined foo
INFO:root:22238: __name__ == '__main__'
INFO:root:22238: pool created
INFO:root:22240: {}: running foo
INFO:root:22239: {}: running foo
INFO:root:22240: {}: running foo
INFO:root:22239: {}: running foo
INFO:root:22240: {}: running foo
INFO:root:22239: {}: running foo
INFO:root:22240: {}: running foo
INFO:root:22239: {}: running foo
INFO:root:22240: {}: running foo
INFO:root:22240: {}: running foo
INFO:root:22238: map completed
INFO:root:22238: output printed
INFO:root:22238: Finished running
tom@fannybawz:~$
```

Try the same thing yourself with the Process version.

Comment: I don't think is my case, the same exactly code works in the interactive interpreter in terminal...

Comment: If it works in the interactive interpreter (and presumably if you run it as a file `python mymodule.py`), but it does not work in IDLE, it suggests the problem is with IDLE.

Comment: Might be worth trying it using Process instead of Pool to see if you can narrow down exactly where the issue is happening in IDLE - it sounds like a call is blocking unexpectedly/indefinitely.

Comment: yes - it's IDLE only, I've tried to pointed out in my very first question! I do get the same error using process, so it's about multiprocessing somehow :(

Comment: So the problem must be related to how IDLE runs your module, right? Can you add some logging to narrow down exactly when/where it blocks? E.g. when calling Process().start() ?

Comment: using Pool it blocks at pool = Pool(2). Using Process with the code provided at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class it blocks at p.join() ... hope it makes sense!

Comment: Interesting. In the Process case that suggests the subprocess is spawned but never finishes. It might be worth adding some logging-to-file so that you can keep track of what the subprocess does, and see if you can work out at what point it gets stuck (assuming it does).

Comment: any suggestions on how to produce that log? xD

Comment: The 'similar question' referenced above is quite different because the issue there (misdiagnosed by most answers) is spawned processes trying to write to a non-existent stdout.  The example here only prints in the master process and runs fine on 2.7.13 on Win10.